# CSS: Background in front of image - how to prevent it?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following situation:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Title
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #thingy {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        background-image: url("bg.png");
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <img src="test.png" alt=""/>
      <div id="thingy">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.png** is the same image, **bg.png** is a 1x4 background image.

The problem is: The element #thingy is displayed in front of the image, so a line goes right through the image. This should not happen, #thingy should be displayed behind the image. Playing with z-index doesn't do anything...

Any hints?

Thanks,
Jost

EDIT: Some more details:
The goal is to get a header banner (**test.png above**), which has a horizontal line under it. The line must span the entire width of the header area (thus width: 100%), the banner must remain centered.

Comment: This happens in chrome and in firefox, so I suppose this is not a browser specific issue.

Comment: Provide fully-qualified URLs for the images (http://") so we can test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring `position: relative` on the image and giving it a z-index corrects the behavior.  See below:

```
#thingy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background-image: url("bg.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#wrapper img {
    position: relative;  
    z-index: 2500;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for sure "thingy" is displayed in front of the image, because it has the position absolute.
z-index can not help in this case, because the image is positioned static and z-index has no influence to it.

I have no idea what you try to achieve, but when you position the image also absolute, then the z-index will work.

EDIT: To the edits to your question it is now a bit clearer what you want. Why don't you put the background-image you have in the moment in thingy ans background-image of your wrapper? If needed positioned to with background-position. Then you center your image in the Wrapper and you are done. You need the "thingy" div for nothing in your case.

Comment: Positioning the image relatively will also correct the behavior.

Comment: that's right, there are different possibilities to handle this problem and I'm pretty sure there will be no position needed at all, if Jost would explain what he tries to do at all.

Comment: Agreed, the question is a bit vague on the details.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a z-index and set the position to the image:

```
#wrapper img {
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

#thingy {
    z-index: 99;
} ​
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this;

http://jsfiddle.net/mtariq/xmYpq/